# How could I control location of external form relative to a pictureBox on another form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, position, point

I'm developing a windows application that is image viewer. This program contain main form to load picture and another form to load swf file into it dynamically .
work of my application is like this : when mouse clicked on pictureBox on main form an object will be created (type of second form) and should locate in correct position.

I have  problem to get correct position. How could do this ?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of child controls on a form is given in *child coordinates*. In other words, in coordinates that are relative to the parent form.

The position of forms is given in *screen coordinates* because their parent is the entire screen.

This is called out in the documentation for the different overloads of the `Location` property.

> **[`Control.Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx):** Gets or sets the coordinates of the upper-left corner of the control relative to the upper-left corner of its container.
>
> **[`Form.Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159414.aspx):** Gets or sets the Point that represents the upper-left corner of the Form in screen coordinates.

So you need to convert the position of the PictureBox on form A from child coordinates into screen coordinates, and then you can use those screen coordinates to set the position of form B.

To do this in WinForms, call the [`Control.PointToScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen.aspx) method:

```
Point childCoords  = myPictureBox.Location;
Point screenCoords = myPictureBox.PointToScreen(childCoords);

myOtherForm.Location = screenCoords;
```

Comment: thanks a lot .that's work but there is another problem .after zoom in/out of my pictureBox and pan ,how could calculate the correct position?

Comment: @LMC Altering the image that is displayed *inside* of the PictureBox does not change the position of the PictureBox control itself. So it should be the same. Otherwise, I don't understand what you mean by "zoom in/out".

Comment: in pictureBox ,there is ability of zoom .i mean after zooming how could calculate the location of exist object of form B ?

Comment: @LMC Are you talking about setting the `PictureBox.SizeMode` property to `PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom`? That does not change the position of the PictureBox control, so you don't need to recalculate anything.

Comment: no ,PictureBox.SizeMode is set to StretchImage .i mean after zooming (by changing the size of pictureBox) for object form (type of B ) how  could caculate the right location?

Comment: If you change the `Location` and/or `Size` of the control, you will need to re-run the example code to find its new relative location.  I don't really understand what you're asking. This doesn't link the two together in any way, it just gives you the position of the control in screen coordinates.   @lmc